# How do you completely unload a swf (sounds and all) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript-3

So, I have web page that uses javascript to let a user select different audio files to listen to (using this player: http://www.macloo.com/examples/audio_player/) which works great in every browser except for any version of IE. After the audio starts playing I can't figure out a programmatic way to make the audio stop playing after the user clicks on another item to listen to. I don't have access to the source of the swf so I'm trying to use javascript to do this. I went so far as to replace the entire body of the page - $("body").html("blank") - but it still played the audio loaded into the swf in it's entirety.

Is there any way I can completely remove a swf from a page (sound and all) just using javascript?

Comment: How your audio player is loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried all of the solutions proposed and they didn't work across all browsers for me. :( What I ended up doing is loading up the flash content in an iframe - when I changed the src of that it would completely and reliably kill the audio that was playing. I think this might have been because the audio appeared to be streaming? Ugh, anyway - iframe time!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
location.href = location.href;
```

That will completely reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
$('object').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may need to use External-interface and call flash method from javascript and that flash method will remove the swf file. If you are using Action-Script 3 with Flash Player 10 then you can use unloadAndStop() method. This method will unload your swf and will remove all its events and sounds etc. it is better to use unloadAndStop() method than unload() method.

And if you want to hide flash from server-page , you have many ways , call page refresh with a variable passed in query string , based on that variable value , you can hide/show your swf file. If you do want to do it with JavaScript then take your swf in Div and hide that Div..